# Issues with adding Input.GetKey inside OnTriggerEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object with a trigger attached and when my player object enters that trigger and the appropriate Raycast position, I can use a key to start a coroutine. But when I press a key, nothing happens.

If I completely remove the Input.GetKey line, everything works perfectly.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Object")
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z))
        {        
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, 2f))
            {
                Debug.Log("Raycast detected.");
                // collisionDetected = true; // attempt 1
                // StartCoroutine(Collide(solidObject)); // attempt 2
            }                
        }
    }                
}

void Update()
{
    if (collisionDetected == true)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Collide(solidObject));
    }
}
```

I have tried several things but nothing has quite worked. I have tried replacing GetKey with GetKeyDown and I have also tried to swap the Input.GetKey and Raycast lines with one another but despite detection still being there, the key input did nothing. I attempted this both with and without a bool, but there was no change.

Comment: The `Input` api should be used from `Update`, and not in Physics functions.  You could store the object until it either leaves the trigger or the key is pressed.  From the docs: `Call this function from the Update function, since the state gets reset each frame`

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it the User would need to already hold down the Z key **before** or latest **just in the exact same frame** as the `OnTriggerEnter` is called. The latter is highly unlikely and the first doesn't sound to be the expected interaction.

It sounds like you rather want to check if you are colliding with an object

```
// stores current colliding object
private Collider currentTrigger;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.CompareTag("Object"))
    {
        // might want to add handling of multiple objects at some point
        // for now simply overwrite
        currentTrigger = col;
    }                
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (currentTrigger == col)
    {
        // reset if this is current
        currentTrigger = null;
    }  
}

void Update()
{
    // is currently colliding?
    if (currentTrigger)
    {
        // was key pressed this frame?
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
        {
            // does raycast hit something?
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, 2f))
            {
                // might even want to check if hitting same object here
                // assuming you have raycast hits on triggers enabled in the settings
                //if(hit.collider == currentTrigger)
                Debug.Log("Raycast detected.");
                StartCoroutine(Collide(solidObject));
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

as mentioned if your raycast is supposed to hit triggers you need to enable it in the [physics settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html) -> **Queries Hit Triggers**